# Какие есть сегменты у программы?

Tags: виртуальная-память

меня начал интересовать вопрос по поводу организации памяти программы. Насколько мне известно, существует 3 основных сегментных регистра: CS, SS, DS. И в них содержится индекс необходимых сегментов. Но сегмент с данными, подразделяется еще на два сегмента: инициализированные данные и bss (поправьте пожалуйста, если мое предположение ошибочно). Как к ним осуществляется доступ, ведь сегментных регистров только 3(мы их уже используем под другие цели), а номера сегментов где-то хранить нужно. Или вот ещё куча, как с ней? Получается это либо часть какого-то сегмента или как? Поправьте меня пожалуйста, если я что-то не так сказал и расскажите что к чему.

Comment: Сегментные регистры (за некоторым исключением) не используются при адресации в программах, работающих в защищенном режиме (в котором обычно работают современные операционные системы).

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. А каким образом тогда происходит адресация?

Comment: Просто используется адрес, как число (например, адрес может целиком лежать в одном регистре общего назначения). Никаких манипуляций с сегментными регистрами для вычисления адреса не нужно.

Comment: "На самом деле" все немного сложнее, поскольку программы работают с адресами в виртуальной памяти, которые "магическим" образом соотносятся с физической памятью, но в любом случае для работы обычных программ постоянное использование сегментных регистров не нужно.

Comment: *Насколько мне известно, существует 3 основных сегментных регистра: CS, SS, DS.* На самом деле больше. *сегмент с данными, подразделяется еще на два сегмента: инициализированные данные и bss* Это совсем иное, хоть и называется тоже сегментами.

Comment: @insolor почему манипуляций с сегментными регистрами не нужно? Чтобы получить доступ к опр. памяти нужно знать номер сегмента и смещение в нём. Номер как раз и будет храниться в каком-нибудь сегментном регистре. Номера сегментов не передаются прямо в адресах, разве не так?

Comment: @Akina, спасибо.  Как тогда в них происходит адресация? И что насчет кучи? Это отдельный сегмент? Или все таки это часть сегмента данных, например?

Comment: Сегментные регистры определяют физическую сегментацию (реальную или виртуальную). Сегменты (не)инициализированных данных, куча - это логическая сегментация памяти, используемой программой. PS. Вы начните хотя бы с изучения адресации памяти в x86 реального режима, что ли... тут всё же не курсы для начинающих.

Comment: @Akina не могли бы вы дать ссылки на несколько хороших источников для изучения?

Comment: Не, не моя область интересов.

Comment: @n1kzzz "почему манипуляций с сегментными регистрами не нужно? Чтобы получить доступ к опр. памяти нужно знать номер сегмента и смещение в нём." - не нужно, достаточно просто адреса, как числа. Память в защищенном режиме не сегментирована.

Comment: По сути сегментные регистры нужны были потому, что размер регистра был 16 бит, что позволяло адресовать 2 ** 16 = 65536 байт (64 КБ) - это и есть размер сегмента. Чтобы адресовать большее количество памяти (больше чем 1 сегмент), и нужна была сегментная адресация. 32-битный регистр позволяет адресовать до 4 ГБ памяти, а 64-битный - до ~16 тысяч петабайт. Никакие дополнительные регистры для адресации не нужны.

Comment: @insolor, правильно ли я понял, что в реальном режиме реализована сегментная организация памяти, а в защищенном - страничная? А что насчёт сегментно-страничной организации памяти?

Comment: @n1kzzz это уже выходит за область моей компетенции)

Answer (score 0):

https://learnc.info/c/program_structure.html?ysclid=l8ri53fqpr493649168

Вроде все спихивается на ОС. Кроме того обычно heap(куча) общая для всех процессов ОС и место в ней выделяется системными вызовами. Хотя возможны вариации. Поправьте есч.

[image: схема расположения C программы в памяти]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).